# How can I implement update and delete in django view?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I am creating a movie review website. In it, I want to be able to allow a User to make one comment on one movie and then Update or Delete that comment. But I am only able to implement POST right now. How do I change the view, html or model?

## Question to ask

How can I keep the comments posted by a user at the top of the comment list so that they can be updated and deleted?

### An example of what we would like to implement is Rotten Tomatoes.

Models.py:

```
class Comment_movie(models.Model):
    comment     = models.TextField(max_length=1000)
    stars       = models.FloatField(
                     blank=False,
                     null=False,
                     default=0, 
                     validators=[MinValueValidator(0.0),
                     MaxValueValidator(10.0)]
                  )

    user        = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    movie       = models.ForeignKey(Movie, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at  = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    updated_at  = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('user', 'movie')
        indexes = [
        models.Index(fields=['user', 'movie']),
        ]
```

views.py:

```
def view_movie_detail(request, movie_id):
    if not(Movie.objects.filter(id=movie_id)):
        Movie(id = movie_id).save()
    movie = Movie.objects.get(id=movie_id)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = Comment_movie_CreateForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            Comment_movie(
                comment = form.cleaned_data['comment'], 
                user = request.user,
                stars = form.cleaned_data['stars'],
                movie = movie
            ).save()
        return redirect('view_movie_detail', movie_id=movie_id)
        
    else:
        form = Comment_movie_CreateForm()
        data = requests.get(f"https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/{movie_id}?api_key={TMDB_API_KEY}&language=en-US")
        recommendations = requests.get(f"https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/{movie_id}/recommendations?api_key={TMDB_API_KEY}&language=en-US")
        comments = reversed(Comment_movie.objects.filter(movie_id=movie_id))
        average = movie.average_stars()
        context = {
            "data": data.json(),
            "recommendations": recommendations.json(),
            "type": "movie",
            "comments": comments,
            "average" : average,
            "form": form,
        }
        return render(request, "Movie/movie_detail.html", context)
```

movie.html:

```
<h2>Comments</h2>
    {% if form.errors %}
        <div class = "error_list">
            {% for errors in form.errors.values %}
                {% for error in errors %}
                    {{ error }}<br>
                {% endfor %}
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    {% endif %}
    <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form }}
        <button type="submit">Post Comment</button>
    </form>
    {% endif %}
    <hr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you want to do multiple actions in one view. <s>One form for each action and a template field to differentiate actions would be a solution.</s> In this specific case, 'create' action and 'update' action can be automatically determined if we take advantage of `unique_together`.

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

def view_movie_detail(request, movie_id):

    # It makes little sense you create a movie with just an id attr
    # So I use get_object_or_404 instead
    movie = get_object_or_404(Movie, id=movie_id)

    try:
        comment_movie = Comment_movie.objects.get(user=request.user, movie=movie)
    except Comment_movie.DoesNotExist:
        comment_movie = None

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.POST.get('action') == 'delete':
            comment_movie.delete()
            return redirect('view_movie_detail', movie_id=movie_id)
        else:
            form = Comment_movie_CreateForm(request.POST, instance=comment_movie)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                return redirect('view_movie_detail', movie_id=movie_id)
    else:
        form = Comment_movie_CreateForm(instance=comment_movie)

    # Put your view logic outside of the conditional expression. 
    # Otherwise your code breaks when the form validates to False
    data = requests.get(f"https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/{movie_id}?api_key={TMDB_API_KEY}&language=en-US")
    recommendations = requests.get(f"https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/{movie_id}/recommendations?api_key={TMDB_API_KEY}&language=en-US")
    comments = reversed(Comment_movie.objects.filter(movie_id=movie_id).exclude(user=request.user))
    average = movie.average_stars()
    context = {
        "data": data.json(),
        "recommendations": recommendations.json(),
        "type": "movie",
        "comments": comments,
        "average" : average,
        "form": form,
        "comment_movie": comment_movie, # NOTE add the comment to context
    }
    return render(request, "Movie/movie_detail.html", context)
```

Note `instance=coment_movie` will make form use instance attribute when rendering in template.

And in your templates, <s>render all three forms, and add ‘action’ to each form. One good place would be the submit button.</s>

```
<h2>Comments</h2>
    {% if form.errors %}
        <div class = "error_list">
            {% for errors in form.errors.values %}
                {% for error in errors %}
                    {{ error }}<br>
                {% endfor %}
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    {% endif %}
    <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form }}
        {% if comment_movie %}
        <button type="submit">Edit Comment</button>
        <button type="submit" name="action" value="delete">Delete Comment</button>
        {% else %}
        <button type="submit">Post Comment</button>
        {% endif %}
    </form>
    {% endif %}
    <hr>
    {% for comment in comments %}
       <div>{{ comment.comment }}</div>
    {% endfor %}
```

<s>Check out [django-multi-form-view](https://github.com/TimBest/django-multi-form-view). This module does not fit your question perfectly, but shares some basic ideas.</s>

Note two addtional submit buttons in template. They are rendered only if comment is not `None`, which means user has made comment before. The second button coresponds to `action='delete'`

To your question: Render the form first, and render the rest comments after the form such that user comment is always at top.

Comment: I would like to have the post appear in the form when a user makes a post.
How can I do this?

Comment: Can you show me the code? I don't know how to do this, so it would be helpful if I could get a concrete code.

Comment: UNIQUE constraint failed: I got the error Movies_comment_movie.user_id, Movies_comment_movie.movie_id. How should I change it?

Comment: Do you have data that conflict with the constraints? Try clear database  column before make migartions

Comment: unique_together = ('user','movie')
indexes = [
         models.Index (fields = ['user','movie']),
         ]
Since it is defined in the model, Update creates a new comment (it seems that it is judged that two comments are created).

Comment: django automatically creates index for ForeignKey fields, so the index meta option are unnecessary. However, it should have nothing to do with unique_togther error. To be honest, I have no idea why it happens

Comment: I changed form.save() into Comment_movie(comment = form.cleaned_data ['comment'],user = request.user,stars = form.cleaned_data ['stars'],movie = movie).save()
Because,  form.save() errored NOT NULL constraint failed: Movies_comment_movie.movie_id

Comment: form = Comment_movie_CreateForm(request.POST, instance=comment_movie)
            if form.is_valid() and request.POST.get('action') == 'update':
                form.save()
                return redirect('view_movie_detail', movie_id=movie_id)
            elif form.is_valid() and request.POST.get('action') == 'create':
                Comment_movie(
                comment = form.cleaned_data['comment'], 
                user = request.user,
                stars = form.cleaned_data['stars'],
                movie = movie
            ).save()

Comment: This was successful.